# Modifying duration jquery timepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, timepicker

I'm using the following UI for date-time combination range selector for my dashboard.
https://github.com/keithhackbarth/jquery-datetime-picker

Now, I need to select a specific range and I want intervals of 1 hour only using my timepicker.

I was able to edit this on a new timepicker div using the "step" function but am not able to do the same in my main date-time combination.

Here's the code for a new timepicker I created and changed step to 60 minutes :

```
<div>
    <input type="text" class="timepicker" >
    </div>

$('.timepicker').timepicker({'step':60});
```

This part is working perfectly with the new step.

Now, my main part of code with the date-time combination is :

```
 <div id="container">
        <div class="example">
            <h3>Select Your Range</h3>
            <p class="datepair" data-language="javascript">
                <input type="text" class="dt_date_start"/>
                <input type="text" class="dt_time_start" /> .........TO............
                <input type="text" class="dt_date_end" />
                <input type="text" class="dt_time_end" />
            </p>
       </div>
 </div>



$('.dt_time_start').timepicker({'minTime': '2:00pm',
    'maxTime': '11:30pm',
    'showDuration': true,'step':60});

$('.dt_time_end').timepicker({'step':60});
```

However, this part is not working properly with the same code etc.
Any suggestions are welcome.
Please tell me what I'm doing wrong in this.

Comment: Did you wrap the Code in the Document.ready, and added the Jquery library?

Comment: Yes, jquery library is added which is the reason the first code snippet runs perfectly.But the second part does not give the expected output.

Comment: I have also tried editing timepicker.js by replacing default step:30 to step:60, but this creates another issue: For a single date, time durations selected are 30 minutes, 1.5 hrs, 2.5hrs, 3.5 hrs and so on. For a selection of different days, it works properly.

Also, then I tried editing datepair.js for the "dt_time_start" and "dt_time_end" with an explicit mention of span:60, this also gives the same result as above.

Kindly let me know if anyone has another approach to turn span to 60 minutes in both time dropdowns.

Comment: So I have solved it myself finally after editing two parts of datepair.js : One is the addition of span : 60 in the classes and second was to remove the issue facing of 30 mins, 1.5 hrs etc, which was done by changing a function of endtime from 30 to 60 merely.

Question is solved, mods can kindly close this.